# TERRAFORM: Modify Values for ZipMap while Transforming Map to new Keys

Tags: terraform, for-in-loop, hcl

I thought this would be easy :frowning:

Goal is to transform this map:

````
```
accounts = {
  "acct-key-1" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fee"
    "private-attribute-2" = "foe"
  }
  "acct-key-2" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fie"
    "private-attribute-2" = "fum"
  }
}
```
````

into this map:

````
```
goodness = {
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1" = {
      "billingcode" = "sys"
      "acct-key" = "acct-key-1" 
  }
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2" = {
      "billingcode" = "sys"
      "acct-key" = "acct-key-2"
  }
}
```
````

As you can see, there are three tasks going on:

1. Create the new map using a guaranteed-unique attribute (future-key) as the key for the new map.  That's not a problem, see code below.
2. Insert the old key as an attribute into the new map
3. Remove some named attributes (private-attribute-n) from the new map

Per code below, ZipMap seems to be the way to go partway there.  Using ZipMap I get a partial result like this:

````
```
partial = {
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fee"
    "private-attribute-2" = "foe"
  }
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fie"
    "private-attribute-2" = "fum"
  }
}
```
````

with a few things wrong with it:

- old key not inserted as an attribute
- private attributes not removed
- old key still present.  Don't really care about that one!

It seems that "all" I need to do is to modify `local.newvalues` to:

- Insert the old key as an attribute, and
- Remove the unwanted values

And I've tried nearly every variant of nested for..in loops I could think of and find on the web, with no success at all, not even enough to show.

The problem seems to be that `local.newvalues` is a tuple, and methods to modify tuples are few and far between.

The logic I've tried to implement would go like:

for  each object in local.newvalues
get the corresponding old key from keys(accts) and insert it
look at other attributes and skip or remove them if they match one of the private keys

The code is simple and goes like this:

````
```
locals {
    # get source map
    accts = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/question.json"))
    newkeys = values(local.accts)[*].future-key
    newvalues = values(local.accts)
    partial = zipmap(
      local.newkeys, local.newvalues
    )
}

output "accounts" {
    value = local.accts
}

output "newkeys" {
    value = local.newkeys
}

output "newvalues" {
    value = local.newvalues
}

output "partial" {
    value = local.partial
}```
````

And the unfinished output like this:

````
```
Outputs:

accounts = {
  "acct-key-1" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fee"
    "private-attribute-2" = "foe"
  }
  "acct-key-2" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fie"
    "private-attribute-2" = "fum"
  }
}
newkeys = [
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1",
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2",
]
newvalues = [
  {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fee"
    "private-attribute-2" = "foe"
  },
  {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fie"
    "private-attribute-2" = "fum"
  },
]
partial = {
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fee"
    "private-attribute-2" = "foe"
  }
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2" = {
    "billingcode" = "sys"
    "future-key" = "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2"
    "private-attribute-1" = "fie"
    "private-attribute-2" = "fum"
  }
}
````

To make code easy to reproduce, I put the initial map in a json file that the code reads and decodes; here it is as question.json:

````
```
{
    "acct-key-1": {
        "future-key": "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1",
        "billingcode": "sys",
        "private-attribute-1": "fee",
        "private-attribute-2": "foe"
    },
    "acct-key-2": {
        "future-key": "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2",
        "billingcode": "sys",
        "private-attribute-1": "fie",
        "private-attribute-2": "fum"
    }  
}
```
````

Ideas much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need zip for that. Just a single for loop is enough:

```
locals {
  goodness = {
    for acc_key, acc_details in local.accts:
      acc_details.future-key => {
        acct-key = acc_key
        billingcode = acc_details.billingcode
      }
  }
}
```

which gives:

```
{
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-1" = {
    "acct-key" = "acct-key-1"
    "billingcode" = "sys"
  }
  "SOME-UNIQUE-VALUE-2" = {
    "acct-key" = "acct-key-2"
    "billingcode" = "sys"
  }
}
```

Comment: Elegant, direct and absolutely perfect.  Thank you so much Marcin!

Comment: I remain curious as to how the list of values (local.newvalues) can be transformed as a matter of academic interest, but inverting the problem to generate only properties needed is like a light in the fog.  Thanks again!

Comment: @rpc No proplem. You can make new question with relevant examples for the "academic interest".